# upgrading hazelcast to > 3.2.5 results in: PortableFactory[-19] is already registered

Tags: java, hazelcast

When I use hazelcast 3.2.5 in my pom.xml everything is working very well. But when I change the hazelcast version to 3.3.1 or to 3.4 then I will get the following error.

Googeling this error message does not give me any hint. So have you seen this message before and how can I fix this?

```
java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: PortableFactory[-19] is already registered! com.hazelcast.client.txn.ClientTxnPortableHook$1@2cb4c3ab -> com.hazelcast.transaction.client.ClientTxnPortableHook$1@13c78c0b
    at com.hazelcast.nio.serialization.PortableHookLoader.register(PortableHookLoader.java:84)
    at com.hazelcast.nio.serialization.PortableHookLoader.load(PortableHookLoader.java:51)
    at com.hazelcast.nio.serialization.PortableHookLoader.<init>(PortableHookLoader.java:41)
    at com.hazelcast.nio.serialization.SerializationServiceImpl.<init>(SerializationServiceImpl.java:85)
    at com.hazelcast.nio.serialization.SerializationServiceBuilder.build(SerializationServiceBuilder.java:174)
    at com.hazelcast.instance.Node.<init>(Node.java:158)
    at com.hazelcast.instance.HazelcastInstanceImpl.<init>(HazelcastInstanceImpl.java:95)
    at com.hazelcast.instance.HazelcastInstanceFactory.constructHazelcastInstance(HazelcastInstanceFactory.java:147)
    at com.hazelcast.instance.HazelcastInstanceFactory.newHazelcastInstance(HazelcastInstanceFactory.java:130)
    at com.hazelcast.instance.HazelcastInstanceFactory.newHazelcastInstance(HazelcastInstanceFactory.java:107)
    at com.hazelcast.core.Hazelcast.newHazelcastInstance(Hazelcast.java:87)
    at kic.engine.main.MQLFactory.getHazelcastInstance(MQLFactory.java:54)
    at kic.engine.v3.gramar.ParserTest.testConfig(ParserTest.java:19)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at org.junit.runners.model.FrameworkMethod$1.runReflectiveCall(FrameworkMethod.java:47)
    at org.junit.internal.runners.model.ReflectiveCallable.run(ReflectiveCallable.java:12)
    at org.junit.runners.model.FrameworkMethod.invokeExplosively(FrameworkMethod.java:44)
    at org.junit.internal.runners.statements.RunBefores.evaluate(RunBefores.java:24)
    at org.junit.internal.runners.statements.RunAfters.evaluate(RunAfters.java:27)
    at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner.run(ParentRunner.java:309)
    at org.junit.runner.JUnitCore.run(JUnitCore.java:160)
    at com.intellij.junit4.JUnit4IdeaTestRunner.startRunnerWithArgs(JUnit4IdeaTestRunner.java:74)
    at com.intellij.rt.execution.junit.JUnitStarter.prepareStreamsAndStart(JUnitStarter.java:211)
    at com.intellij.rt.execution.junit.JUnitStarter.main(JUnitStarter.java:67)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
    at com.intellij.rt.execution.application.AppMain.main(AppMain.java:134)
```

Comment: The -19 afaik indicates an internal portable factory (so one from us). So I find it strange to get this particular exception because it would suggest that we are registering our own factories more than once. Can you create a unit test that reproduces the exception? I see that you already are making use of a unit test, so perhaps sufficient to copy/paste what you have so we can have a look at it.

Comment: @pveentjer Hmmm there must be something weired in my project. When I strip out everything to a new Project just containig the tests hazelcast will start fine ... now this is even worse :-)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I think I have found the problem in the classpath. My ide contained both hazelcasts 3.2.5 and 3.4 in the classpath. Usually my ide is smater than I but not this time :-)